# SQL Server logic within EXECUTE statement ignoring transactions

Tags: sql-server, transactions, execute

I've encountered this in SQL Server 2019 (v15).

This is a simplified version of much larger stored procedure. But this shows the behavior I am puzzled by, inside the exec there is a transaction, this transaction is then committed, then error is thrown.

I would expect that this change is persisted, but it's not, looks like the whole content of EXEC statement is reverted.

Can someone explain the behavior in this scenario?

Here is the code sample to reproduce this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (test int);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1);

BEGIN TRY
    SELECT 'start'
    EXEC(' EXEC(  ''
    BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
    SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
    INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (2); 
    COMMIT; 
    THROW 1;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
    INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (3); 
    COMMIT; 
    '' )' )
    SELECT 'after EXEC'
    THROW
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
     EXEC ('ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;');
     SELECT 'In CATCH Block'
END CATCH

SELECT 'After END CATCH'
 
SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

Comment: You can't `throw 1;` Rest isn't even getting run. Add SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE() in the TRY/CATCH handler. You can't throw if not in try catch either. Might wanna change to RAISERROR

Comment: You can't `COMMIT` a transaction that is never existed. You have a syntax error so the batch is never run. T-SQL is a compiled language; if that compilation fails then *none* of that batch is run.

Comment: *"You can't throw if not in try catch either."* This is completely incorrect, @siggemannen . You can `THROW` where ever you want, but you can't do `THROW;` (no error message, no number) outside of `TRY...CATCH`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SzxWUxPu)

Comment: @ThomA sorry, i meant rethrow

Comment: Move the `THROW` before the `END TRY` to after the `BEGIN CATCH` to rethrow errors from the dynamic SQL, including compilation errrors.

Comment: Also `THROW` must be terminated with `;` as should all other statements

Comment: You're edit completely invalids my answer, this is very much frowned upon. If you have asked the *wrong* question, ask a new question; don't change th question to invalid responses (answers) you have got.

Comment: Why `EXEC ('ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;');` and not simply `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;`? You should check if there IS a transaction before trying a rollback here. ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trancount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN question related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/980143/125981

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is *not* the transaction, it is your T-SQL, it contains a syntax error. WE can see this if we expose the error within the `CATCH` with something like `PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()`, which shows us the error inside the `TRY` is:

> Incorrect syntax near ';'.

A syntax error means that the **entire** batch is *not* run, and if the batch doesn't run, there is no transaction as it also *never* ran.

The syntax error is your `THROW 1;`; you can't `THROW` an arbitrary error number. The syntax for `THROW` is either `THROW;` or `THROW <Error Number>, <Error Message>, <Error State>;`; you must pass *all* the parameters, or none. If you are using no parameters, this is known as a "rethrow" and can *only* appear inside a `CATCH`.

For your SQL to work as you want, you need to correct the syntax, and pass 3 parameters to `THROW`. For example:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;
GO
CREATE TABLE my_table (test int);
GO
INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES (1);
GO
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT 'start';
    EXEC (' EXEC(  ''
    BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
    SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
    INSERT into my_table values (2); 
    COMMIT; 
    THROW 78912, N''''A non-descript error'''',16;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION; 
    INSERT into my_table values (3); 
    COMMIT; '' )');
    SELECT 'after EXEC' AS [throw];
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    EXEC ('ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;');
    SELECT 'In CATCH Block';
END CATCH;
SELECT 'After END CATCH';
GO
SELECT *
FROM my_table;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.my_table
```

This returns the results you expected:

| test |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

It also produces the follow error:

> The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

This is expected, as the `THROW` is after the `COMMIT` and before the next `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, so there was no transaction to rollback. Though, moving the `THROW` to after the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` will result in a different error.

> Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.

When dealing with tranasctions in deffered batches, like this, you need to handle the transactions in the same scope. Jumping out to the outer scope, and then creating a new inner scope to rollback a tranasction from a *completely different scope* won't work.